# Can I create a lookup object of functions in TS that share an object param with different type unions?

Tags: typescript, type-safety, union-types

Let's say I have these functions that share the same signature:

```js
type ProcessFunction<U> = (options: { type: U }) => void;

const createStuff: ProcessFunction<"monkey" | "dog"> = ({ type }) => { /* */ };
const deleteStuff: ProcessFunction<"cat" | "dinosaur"> = ({ type }) => { /* */ };
const updateStuff: ProcessFunction<"elephant" | "giraffe"> = ({ type }) => { /* */ };
```

If I want to call them dynamically depending on an argument, I'd probably put them on an object:

```js
const Processors = {
    createStuff,
    deleteStuff,
    updateStuff
};
```

And then try to do a dynamic lookup and get the right function:

```js
// This simulates a random argument
const processorKeyArgument = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'createStuff' : 'deleteStuff';
const processor = Processors[processorKey];
```

However, this function doesn't share the signatures above. The reason is that the `options` type is now `never`. This happens because:

```
The intersection
'{ type: "monkey" | "dog"; } & { type: "cat" | "dinosaur"; }'
was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting 
types in some constituents.
```

From what I understand, that makes sense because both share different `type` properties. However, this means that creating a lookup object of these functions is impossible without bypassing TS with type assertions:

```js
const processor = Processors[processorKey];
processor({ type: typeArgument } as never);
```

Is this assessment of the situation correct? Is there are a satisfying workaround to this issue?

I have thought of:

- Giving up on consuming this in a type-safe way and using `as never`, which sounds weird tbh.
- Type `type` as string in the signature, and type-cast inside every function to their required union type.

But none of them seem clear enough.